# Getting InvalidUseOfMatchingException or NullPointerException when all test run together

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5, springmockito

Getting following exceptions when run all tests together but works as expected when executed individually

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "[Ljava.lang.Class;.clone()" because ".parameterTypes" is null

Comment: Please provide some of your Code. Otherwise it is impossible to see whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you have mocked java.lang.reflect.Method (or any java reflection types) in one of your test classes?

use getClass().getMethod() like approach to get it done instead of mocking relect types becasue java not allows to do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).